# Starting Fragments in view pager is causing illegal State Exception?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a use case where I am splitting the main screen in two layouts. Top layout would run a video(Separate fragment). The below screen should have multiple screens controlled by viewpager. Each slide of viewpager would be a separate fragment. Below is my code in main activity

```
    SampleVideoFragment sampleVideoFragment = new SampleVideoFragment();
    SecondFragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.firstlayout, sampleVideoFragment, sampleVideoFragment.getTag()).commit();
    //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.secondlayout, secondFragment, secondFragment.getTag()).commit();
    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpagerID);
    setupViewPager();
    setCurrentFragment(0);

private void setupViewPager() {
    mBottomFragmentPageAdaptar = new BottomFragmentPageAdaptar(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mBottomFragmentPageAdaptar.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "Fragment1");
    mBottomFragmentPageAdaptar.addFragment(new Fragment2(), "Fragment2");
    mBottomFragmentPageAdaptar.addFragment(new Fragment3(), "Fragment3");
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mBottomFragmentPageAdaptar);
}

public void setCurrentFragment(int position){
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
}
```

I am new to Android development too. I suspect it is related to the same fragmentManger being used is causing this. Any input or direction would definitely help.

Attaching Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:2179)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2211)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:167)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1238)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:663)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:625)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:606)
    at com.chooly.tenplusfive.InStreamModeActivity.setCurrentFragment(InStreamModeActivity.java:61)
    at com.chooly.tenplusfive.GameChatFragment.onCreateView(GameChatFragment.java:34)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2215)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:167)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1238)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:267)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:618)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: _"Starting Fragments in view pager is causing illegal State Exception"_ - no one can see the exception!

Answer (score 1):

`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` uses `commitNowAllowingStateLoss()` - the `commitNow()` calls cannot happen when another FragmentTransaction has a `commit()` operation happening at the same time.

You can update your FragmentTransaction to use `commitNow()` which will ensure that your operation is completed before `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` fills in its Fragments.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
  .replace(R.id.firstlayout, sampleVideoFragment, sampleVideoFragment.getTag())
  .commitNow();
```

Comment: Thanks Ian for the reply. My SDK  version 27
Even after adding the below. I am getting the same exception
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.firstlayout, sampleVideoFragment, sampleVideoFragment.getTag()).commitNow();

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to my Fragments that I was using in ViewPager. I was trying to set the current fragment position in every fragment this is the code in the fragment 
mActivity.setCurrentFragment(POSITION);
setCurrentFragment is a method in my main activity.

This was try to change the state of the FragmentStatemanger causing illegal state Exception.

I after digging I realised i just need to instantiate the Fragments and rest all is taken care by ViewPager.